# How to get temporal sequence by mysql

Tags: mysql

In my table there is an id column, a date column and a status column like this:

```
ID    DATE    STATUS
1     0106      A
1     0107      A
1     0112      A
1     0130      B
1     0201      A
2     0102      C
2     0107      C
```

I want to get a temporal sequence of each ID. Which means if in the neighboring time one id is in the same status, then the former ones will be omitted. The query result is like:

```
ID    DATE    STATUS
1     0112      A
1     0130      B
1     0201      A
2     0107      C
```

How can I realize it by MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use variable to do this:

```
select `id`, `date`, `status`
from (
    select *, @rowno:=if(@grp = `STATUS`, @rowno + 1 , 1) as rowno, @grp := `STATUS`
    from yourtable
    cross join (select @grp := null, @rowno := 0) t
    order by `id`, `date` desc
) t1
where rowno = 1
order by `id`, `date`
```

[<kbd>SqlFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29842/20)

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you again, I am just wondering what should I do if I want to get the start date and end date together instead of only the end date?

Comment: @natsuapo And what is your expected result?

Comment: For ID 1, it is like:  `ID: 1; start_date: 0106; end_date 0112; status A `

Comment: This is quite a different question. Please ask a new question on SO. @natsuapo

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much!