# How to simplify sequence data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have asked a question on [How to get temporal sequence by mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521510/how-to-get-temporal-sequence-by-mysql) before. There I want to get a simplified sequence with the latest date. 
Now I want to get the start date and end date of each sequence. Suppose that the table is still like this:

```
ID    DATE    STATUS
1     0106      A
1     0107      A
1     0112      A
1     0130      B
1     0201      A
2     0102      C
2     0107      C
```

and I want to get the result like this:

```
ID    START_DATE    END_DATE    STATUS
1       0106          0112        A
1       0130          0130        B
1       0201          0201        A
2       0102          0107        C
```

I tried to adapt the answer of former question to it though but failed. I am wondering how I can realize it.

Comment: I though about this for a bit.  And given I don't know what bells and whistles are available  in MySQL (T/SQL now has lead and lag functions which might be applicable).  I couldn't think of a straight-forward pure SQL solution (i.e set operations only).  However, and interative approach is straight forward.  Order that data the way you have it, and iterate through it, and detect when ever the id or state changes over the previouss row.   That's a start or end time depend or whether the state or id is changing.  Insert a row in a new table for each transition.

Comment: you can use some trick using stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this

```
 SELECT * FROM T;
+------+------+--------+
| ID   | DATE | STATUS |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |  106 | A      |
|    1 |  107 | A      |
|    1 |  112 | A      |
|    1 |  130 | B      |
|    1 |  201 | A      |
|    2 |  102 | C      |
|    2 |  107 | C      |
+------+------+--------+
```

It's quite straightforward to allocate a block and seqno using this

```
SELECT  T.ID,T.DATE,T.STATUS,
            IF(STATUS <> @PREVS,@RN:=@RN+1,@RN:=@RN) RNBLOCK ,
            IF(STATUS = @PREVS,@RN2:=@RN2+1,@RN2:=1) RNSEQ ,
            @PREVS:=STATUS PSTATUS 
FROM        (SELECT @RN:=1) RNBLOCK, (SELECT @RN2:=0) RNSEQ,(SELECT @PREVS:=NULL) P, T
```

To give this

```
+------+------+--------+---------+-------+---------+
| ID   | DATE | STATUS | RNBLOCK | RNSEQ | PSTATUS |
+------+------+--------+---------+-------+---------+
|    1 |  106 | A      | 1       |     1 | A       |
|    1 |  107 | A      | 1       |     2 | A       |
|    1 |  112 | A      | 1       |     3 | A       |
|    1 |  130 | B      | 2       |     1 | B       |
|    1 |  201 | A      | 3       |     1 | A       |
|    2 |  102 | C      | 4       |     1 | C       |
|    2 |  107 | C      | 4       |     2 | C       |
+------+------+--------+---------+-------+---------+
```

So now we have isolated the blocks and know the min seq no (1) and the max seqno and we can push them into a table

```
drop table t1;
CREATE  TABLE `t1` (
    `ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `DATE` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `STATUS` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rnblock` int null default null,
    `rnseq` int null default null,
    `pstatus` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

and create a simple min max join

```
SELECT   T2.ID,T2.DATE,T3.DATE,T2.STATUS FROM
(       
SELECT   T1.RNBLOCK,MAX(T1.RNSEQ)  MAXSEQ
FROM        T1
GROUP       BY RNBLOCK
) S 
JOIN        T1 T2 ON T2.RNBLOCK = S.RNBLOCK AND T2.RNSEQ = 1
JOIN        T1 T3 ON T3.RNBLOCK = S.RNBLOCK AND T3.RNSEQ = S.MAXSEQ
```

to get this

```
+------+------+------+--------+
| ID   | DATE | DATE | STATUS |
+------+------+------+--------+
|    1 |  106 |  112 | A      |
|    1 |  130 |  130 | B      |
|    1 |  201 |  201 | A      |
|    2 |  102 |  107 | C      |
+------+------+------+--------+
```

The downside is that you have to create a table to make it work.

Or you could use this rather ungainly code which does not use an intermediate table

```
select   u.id,u.date,v.date,u.status from
(
select   s.rnblock,s.status,min(s.rnseq) minseq,max(s.rnseq) maxseq
from
(
SELECT  T.ID,T.DATE,T.STATUS,
            IF(STATUS <> @PREVS,@RN:=@RN+1,@RN:=@RN) RNBLOCK ,
            IF(STATUS = @PREVS,@RN2:=@RN2+1,@RN2:=1) RNSEQ ,
            @PREVS:=STATUS PSTATUS 
FROM        (SELECT @RN:=1) RNBLOCK, (SELECT @RN2:=0) RNSEQ,(SELECT @PREVS:=NULL) P, T
) s
group       by s.rnblock,s.status
) T
join
(SELECT     T.ID,T.DATE,T.STATUS,
            IF(STATUS <> @PREVS2,@RN3:=@RN3+1,@RN3:=@RN3) RNBLOCK ,
            IF(STATUS = @PREVS2,@RN4:=@RN4+1,@RN4:=1) RNSEQ ,
            @PREVS2:=STATUS PSTATUS 
FROM        (SELECT @RN3:=1) RNBLOCK, (SELECT @RN4:=0) RNSEQ,(SELECT @PREVS2:=NULL) P, T
) u  on u.rnblock = t.rnblock and u.rnseq = minseq
join
(SELECT     T.ID,T.DATE,T.STATUS,
            IF(STATUS <> @PREVS3,@RN5:=@RN5+1,@RN5:=@RN5) RNBLOCK ,
            IF(STATUS = @PREVS3,@RN6:=@RN6+1,@RN6:=1) RNSEQ ,
            @PREVS3:=STATUS PSTATUS 
FROM        (SELECT @RN5:=1) RNBLOCK, (SELECT @RN6:=0) RNSEQ,(SELECT @PREVS3:=NULL) P, T
) v  on v.rnblock = t.rnblock and v.rnseq = maxseq
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I have just thought out a method though it seems very stupid. The method is just executing the code from [How to get temporal sequence by mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521510/how-to-get-temporal-sequence-by-mysql) twice(by different order) and join these two tables.

Comment: It seems that join will face some problems.